# Clickable file links from in-text reference

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, natbib, external-files

I am currently using natbib to reference articles that I have in Mendeley.  I have figured out how to get clickable links such that clicking on the in-text reference brings me to the actual reference at the end of my document, however, I am wondering whether clicking on my in-text reference can open the file that it corresponds to (in Mendeley or as a separate PDF)?  And if so, how?

MWE:

```
\usepackage{natbib, lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-3]

\citep{AuthorYear}

\bibliographystyle{APA}
\bibliography{FileLocation}

\end{document}
```

Clicking on "citep{.}" jumps me to the reference section where it is cited, I want to instead open the file itself.

Thanks